# How to type un-perpendicular?

Tags: symbols

How to type un-perpendicular ?
I found \nparallel for unparallel from amssymb package, however I only found \nvdash which is rotated. Are there another alternatives?

Comment: @Mico Whoops, missed the duplicate. Good catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\( \not\perp \)
\end{document}
```

[image: amssymb sample]

In XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, replace `amssymb` with `unicode-math`.  Or load the font package of your choice.

Comment: Thank. That is exact what I need.